# how to remove filled.contour interior grid?

Tags: r, contour

looks like filled.contour function has been updated, and now it automatically adds a white grid inside the plot (inside filled contour plot area), but I don't know how to remove it.

i will give a little example:

```
x <- 1:12
y <- 1:12
xvals <- c(2,4,7,10,14,21,30,60,90,120,180,365)
fx <- as.numeric(as.factor(xvals))
filled.contour(fx, y, outer(x,y),
               plot.axes= {
                   axis(2)  ## plain
                   axis(1,at=fx,labels=xvals)
               })
```

1. Plot before:

[image]

2. Plot Now:

[image]

Thanks,
Ricardo Faria.

Comment: I'm sorry, but my question is different, I'm trying to remove those white lines inside the plot.

Comment: What version of R are you using?

Comment: R version 3.2.4 (2016-03-10)

Comment: I cannot replicate the issue with R 3.2.5.  My plot has no grid lines.

Comment: @Jota,  are you in windows or mac?

Comment: i had R 3.2.3 (linux), R 3.2.4 (os x), R 3.2.5 (OS X). I changed background to black : `par(bd="black")` for the plot and on both OS X versions I see black lines and on the linux one I don't see any. It looks like it's in the C code vs the source for `filled.contour()` proper.

Comment: @hrbrmstr what can I do now? I tried in a windows machine and have a perfect plot without that white grid...

Comment: `utils::bug.report()` (which will take you to a web form)

Comment: What OS are you using? I have the same problem in Mac OS X.

Comment: Sorry i just saw you post now, now i have El Sierra and have the same thing happening

Answer (score 1):

A solution I found is to set the color of the grid to transparent inside the function "grid", like this:

```
filled.contour(fx, y, outer(x,y), plot.axes= {
axis(2)  ## plain
axis(1,at=fx,labels=xvals)
grid(col=rgb(1,1,1,0))
               })
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the color attribute as shown below:

```
filled.contour(fx, y, col = terrain.colors(23),outer(x,y),
           plot.axes= {
             axis(2)  ## plain
             axis(1,at=fx,labels=xvals)
           })
```

The output image is:
    [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Elcb.jpg

Comment: already tried you solution and still gives me those white lines inside plot

Comment: Try this, now there is no white bars:    ``filled.contour(fx, y, col = terrain.colors(23),outer(x,y),
               plot.axes= {
                 axis(2)  ## plain
                 axis(1,at=fx,labels=xvals)
               })``

Comment: unhappily I still see that white grid inside the plot area. have you tried the solution yourself?

Comment: Yes. Can i add the image here, i don't how to add image here.

Comment: I believe you, but still have that white grid inside plot area: [Gopal plot example](http://imgur.com/wS0L1mg). Use (imgur.com) if want to upload a image.

Comment: I have edited the answer with output image. Please have a look. If u want fully same color then instead of 23, use the value above 200

Comment: Thanks a lot, i simply don't understand why I'm getting those grids, what R version you are using and os?

Comment: R version 3.2.3 and windows10 OS

Comment: I'm starting to loose hopes, really don't know what to do.

Comment: @RicardoFaria Have you attempted to contact the author (or R folks) about this ?  The R documentation indicate that "Ross Ihaka" and "R-core" are the authors.

Comment: @steveb already opened a new file bug in:  https://bugs.r-project.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=16846

Answer (score 0):

For me the  the underlying issue was related to shiny and the ragg package: https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ragg/index.html. By setting options(shiny.useragg = FALSE) it solved the gridding issue!

Answer (score -2):

Do not worry about it too much (keep your codes). If you export it to pdf, the white interior gridlines will disappear;

Before:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BzWhW.png)

after export to pdf
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m5qQ2.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).